# Add Site Collection Administrator SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, 2007, site-collection

Is it possible to add a site collection administrator to all sites under a web application in SharePoint 2007. I can see how to do this for SharePoint 2010 upwards but not 2007. I was hoping to do this via powershell.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's been a while, but I would use WebApplication Policy

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott thanks, I did come across this but not sure what the performance hit would be like. I've asked the question in here if you are interested.

Comment: Two benefits. Fire and forget. The setting applies today and to any sites created tomorrow. Also, another site collection admin cannot change it.

Comment: So you would say it's ok to do? Ok across all versions of SharePoint 2007 up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SharePoint 2007, you have to do little tweak in the blow script. This script set multiple users as Site collection admins for multiple sites.

- 1st create a text file and write all the site collections url in it.
- Enter the User name, email id and name in the Target??? variable

Here is code

```
# For SharePoint 2007 compatibility 
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint") 

# Get the user credentials here. Replace below ones with the corresponding 
# value for the user 
$TargetUserDomainID = "contoso\parkumar", "adprod\kbhanu", "contoso\mideshmu" 
$TargetUserEmail = "pkumar@contoso.com", "KBhanu@contoso.com","mideshmu@contoso.com" 
$TargetUserLogOnName = "Kumar, Paritosh", "Bhanu, Kedar", "Deshmukh, Mihir" 

# Specifies path for text file containing SharePoint site collection urls 
# This file should contain root site paths for site collections 
$Siteslist = Get-Content -Path "D:\Solutions\SitesList.txt" 

# Runs for every site collection 
foreach($Siteurl in $Siteslist) 
{ 
    # Output site collection name and get root site from SharePoint. 
    Write-Output "" 
    Write-Output "Working on site $Siteurl" 
    $Site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($SiteUrl) 
    $Web = $Site.Rootweb 

    # Runs for every user 
    for($count = 0; $count -lt $TargetUserDomainID.count ;$count++) 
    { 
        Try 
        { 
            # Add user to the site first and updates site 
            $Web.SiteUsers.Add($($TargetUserDomainID[$count]), $($TargetUserEmail[$count]),$($TargetUserLogOnName[$count]), "") 
            $TargetUser = $web.EnsureUser($($TargetUserDomainID[$count])) 
            $web.Update() 

            # Set user as site collection admin 
            if($TargetUser.IsSiteAdmin) 
            { 
                Write-Host "$($TargetUserLogOnName[$count]) is already added on this site" 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                $TargetUser.IsSiteAdmin = $true 
                $TargetUser.Update() 
                write-host "Added $($TargetUserLogOnName[$count]) as admin" -ForegroundColor Green 
            } 
        } 
        Catch 
        { 
            Write-Host $error[0].Exception.Message -foreground red 
        } 
    }     
}
```

Download complete script from here: [Add Multiple Users as Site Collection Admin for Multiple Site Collections](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Add-Multiple-Users-as-057f8652)

Comment: Thanks. I get this when I try and run it : Exception setting "IsSiteAdmin": "You need to be a site collection administrator to set this property."

Comment: Sorted it now. If i wrap the for loop in the following [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::RunWithElevatedPrivileges({ it works. Thanks